# Facebook Like button not working in IE 11 - possibly a CORS issue?

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer

I'm implementing like buttons to my web. As usual, everything works everywhere except for IE (now version 11).

**Relevant code parts:**

HTML prologue:

```
<html lang="cs" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

FB SDK (loaded before the first like button):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=2...6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://expedicemars.eu/test_version/ucastnik/profily/profil/EM-14-042" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Normal browsers just display a like button.

IE issues the following error:

```
SEC7118: Request XMLHttpRequest for http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/tghYL-krfL8.js requires specification CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).
File: like.php
```

I've tried almost everything I found on the web and with no help. Please note that instructing the users to lower their security settings is no way for me =)

For reference, you may visit http://expedicemars.eu/test_version/ucastnik/profily/profil/EM-14-042 .

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm surprised that Facebook doesn't talk about it. Implementing the buttons using the iFrame method is a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using the FBML or iframe solutions. I've been able to show the like button in IE11 using the FBML method, if you don't want to include an iframe on the page. I still get the CORS message when I include the SDK reference, but it works.

Comment: @peci1 Did you find a solution?

Comment: I gave it up. It might have started working, but I haven't tested it for more than a year.